# will having a different academic name than official name hurt?

Tags: personal-name, certification

My academic name school+B.Sc. is `Rajesh` without a surname, and in passport and all other docs it is `Rajesh Lobhani` that has the surname. I live in India and wish to work and do phd in Australia.

Doing M.Sc. currently so do I change my name(for M.Sc) or let it be? The procedure involves changing Xth and XII standard school name, and it very difficult.

Comment: In what context? Are you concerned about application to PhD, or publication?

Comment: @MJeffryes about phd in Australia and also an academic job as a professor.

Comment: I would expect that, when you apply for Ph.D. studies in Australia, you can use the version of your name that appears on your passport, and you can explain in your cover letter that your B.Sc. and M.Sc. documents are under the shorter version of your name.  Once you get your Ph.D. under the long version of your name, you should have no difficulty using the same version when applying for jobs --- at that point, it's unlikely that anyone will care about your B.Sc. or M.Sc. documents.

Comment: I don't really know how that bureaucracy works, but you might find this site useful: http://www.researcherid.com it's an interesting tool to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @AndreasBlass hi, what do you mean "cover letter", and explain it to whom, I doubt they will listen to me.

Comment: I meant to explain it to the admissions committee, but I suppose my mention of a cover letter is just out of date. You'll probably be applying through some web interface, which gives no room for a cover letter.  So ignore "cover letter" and put an explanation in whatever the admissions committee will read --- perhaps a footnote in your statement of purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Many academics have had multiple names because of marriage, immigration, or other changes. I don't anticipate this being a problem in your case. As [AndreasBlass suggested in the comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98379/will-having-a-different-academic-name-than-official-name-hurt#comment254557_98379), just mention it in your application materials somewhere.